# Is there any Error in Azure QnA Maker service?

Tags: azure, bots, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to make a knowledge base and I'm getting an Http 500 response when I try to test the KB directly in the platform qnamaker.ia furthermore I published and queried with postman but looks like a problem with the service, Does anyone know if there is any general error with the service?
I'm trying to upload a (.PDF) file with a standard S price, I tried with different locations but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to [create knowledge base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/manage-knowledge-bases) and test in the [qnamaker.ai](https://www.qnamaker.ai/). Please find the snapshot for the same. Please feel free to retry.
[image]